# Criteria for monotonicity of one-variable functions

Tags: functions, inequality, elementary-functions

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called monotone if $f$ satisfies one of the following conditions
$$
x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}, x_1<x_2\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f(x_1)\leq f(x_2) \quad (1)
$$
$$
x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}, x_1<x_2\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f(x_1)\geq f(x_2) \quad (2)
$$
We consider a condition to combine both (1) and (2) as following
$$
x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}, x_1<x_2<x_3\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \min\{f(x_1),f(x_3)\}\leq f(x_2)\leq\max\{f(x_1),f(x_3)\}\quad (3)
$$
It means that $f$ is monotone if and only if (3) is satisfied. Below is our proof of this fact.

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that $f$ is monotone. Then either (1) or (2) is satisfied. Clearly, (3) holds.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that (3) holds. We will prove either (1) or (2) holds and so $f$ is monotone.

Suppose that $x_1<x_2$ and $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$. Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $x<x_1<y<x_2<z$. We will prove that $f(x)\leq f(x_1)\leq f(y)\leq f(x_2)\leq f(z)$. Observe that

- (3) and $x_1<y<x_2, f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$ imply $f(x_1)\leq f(y)\leq f(x_2)$
- (3) and $x<x_1<y, f(x_1)\leq f(y)$ imply $f(x)\leq f(x_1)\leq f(y)$
- (3) and $y<x_2<z, f(y)\leq f(x_2)$ imply $f(y)\leq f(x_2)\leq f(z)$

Hence (1) holds if there exist $x_1<x_2$ such that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$. 
If there exist $x_1<x_2$ such that $f(x_1)\geq f(x_2)$ then
(2) is proved similarly to (1).

Our aim is to find a **shorter proof** and **an intuition** of this fact.

Comment: In the $\impliedby$ direction, you need to prove that *either* (1) *or* (2) holds.

Comment: Thank you. I revised the typo.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @smcc Our aim is to find a **shorter proof** and **an intuition** of this fact.